# What's the correct syntax of copying a UIViewController?

Tags: swift2

I would like to copy an instance of a UIViewController.

Something like this:

```
gOriginViewController = self.copy() as! DiscoveryViewController
```

Which gives me the runtime error:

```
Bliss2.DiscoveryViewController copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8b4440cd70'
```

What's the correct syntax of doing a copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIViewController` does not implement `NSCopying`, and thus cannot be copied using `copy()`. You can use `NSKeyedArchiver` to do this:

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self)
let copy = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! DiscoveryViewController
```